# Echo json data in php for data table use

Tags: php, arrays, json, datatable

I have been trying to echo json array data, but I am getting error. I have not done it before. I want to use it for datatable.

Here is what I have tried to do, but it shows error from, but if I copy the return text and save it in php folder it works fine. Please I need help to fix it.

```
<?php
try {
    $db_conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
    $db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $users_stmt = $db_conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
    $users_stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $users_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        //json_encode($users_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
        $dataarray = '
            [
                "'.$row['username'].'",
                "'.$row['fullname'].'",
                "'.$row['email'].'",
                "'.$row['siteright'].'",
                "2011/04/25",
                "$320,800"
            ],
        ';

    }
} catch (PDOException $e) { echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();}

echo '{<br/>
    "data": [<br/>'
    .$dataarray.
    '<br/>[
      "Donna Snider",
      "Customer Support",
      "New York",
      "4226",
      "2011/01/25",
      "$112,000"
    ]<br/>
  ]<br/>
}';
?>
```

I want it to look like this

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",
      "5421",
      "2011/04/25",
      "$320,800"
    ],
    [
      "Donna Snider",
      "Customer Support",
      "New York",
      "4226",
      "2011/01/25",
      "$112,000"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: $dataarray=array();  while ($row = $users_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){


    $dataarray[] = $row;
           }       echo '<pre>';  echo json_encode($dataarray); echo '</pre>';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do in this way -

```
while ($row = $users_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $dataarray['data'][] = array(
                           $row['username'], $row['fullname'], 
                           $row['email'], $row['siteright'], 
                           2011/04/25, $320,800
                         );
}
$jsonData = json_encode($dataarray);

print_r($jsonData); // your json output
```

Answer (score 3):

[reference link JSON_PRETTY_PRINT](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)

```
while ($row = $users_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$dataarray['data'][] = array(
                       $row['username'], $row['fullname'], 
                       $row['email'], $row['siteright'], 
                       2011/04/25, $320,800
                     );
}

 $json_data = json_encode($newData,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);  

 echo $json_data;
```

Comment: If you're sending `$json_data` to an area inside HTML tags, you can put the data between <pre> tags so the whitespaces aren't ignored.  This way, you can see the formatting you put together using `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`.  Example: `echo "<pre>$jsonData</pre>";` .

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($jsonData);     //  instead of echo
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: i still get this error `DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1`

Comment: I guess is an AJAX response, then remove <pre> tags, whole document has to start with { and end with } without any breaks etc. then you can use echo with JSON string